# RadioGroup change value

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, radio-group

I have a place holder in this radioGroup where I want the user to be able to edit the value. I am not sure the best way to do this and wanted to see any anyone has some ideas. I have some events but they dont look like anything that will change the value.

https://dojo.telerik.com/@mcdevitt/eFULiqeS

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the RadioGroup does not have a setOptions method implemented, so you will have to destroy the RadioGroup and re-initialize it with the desired options - [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/ucEnapIG).

Comment: do I need the kendoMultiSelect any way to change the RadioGroup  item to a label?

Comment: No, I used it just as an example for some random data to pass to the [items](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/radiogroup/configuration/items) configuration of the RadioGroup